# jQuery listviewbeforefilter, limit listview items

Tags: jquery, listview

I am trying to limit the number of listview items that are visible to 5. The airports variable is a string structured as jsonp. The code is working as shown below but I cannot figure out how to limit the number of items that appear in the listview. I need to limit this number because the airports variable contains thousands of items. Thanks for your help!

```
$( "#destinationListview" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 3 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.each( airports, function ( i, val ) {
             html += "<li class='destination' id='" + val.code + "'>" + val.name + ", " + val.location + "</li>";
        });
        $ul.html( html );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");

        $(".destination").click(function() {
            $( data.input ).val($(this).attr("id"));
            $("#destination").val($(this).attr("id"));
            $("#destinationListview li").hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing airports is an array, so I made a quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/av94U/

What you want to do is to separate out the list items you want to use in your `ul`. As you said, you only want 5 visible, so you should get the five airports you want to display in your list by extracting them from your array of airports, like:

```
var listItems = airports.length > 5 ? airports.slice(-5) : airports;
```

Then use the `listItems` in your `$.each( airports, ...)`-call.

Answer (score 0):

To show only the first five list items it would be like this

```js
'''javascript
var listItems = airports.length > 5 ? airports.slice(0,5) : airports;
'''
```